# MySQL self-referencing JOIN

Tags: join, self-reference, mysql5

I have two tables:

```
Customers (
    int(11) Id, 
    varchar(255) Name, 
    int(11) Referred_ID -- Referred_ID being reference to an Id field 
                        -- (no key on that field) and 
)
```

the other table being:

```
Invoices (
    int(11) Id, 
    date Billing_date, 
    int(11) Customer_ID
)
```

I want to select `Id`, `Billing_date` of the invoice AND most important, customer's `Name` this customer refers to.

Now I'm only able to select his referrer's ID by a query like this one:

```
SELECT Invoices.Id, Invoices.Billing_date, Customers.Name, Referred_ID
    FROM Invoices 
    INNER JOIN Customers ON Invoices.Customer_Id = Customers.Id;
```

How should I modify my query to replace that Referred_ID by its owner name?

It's a MySQL from something like 2015, by the way.

Comment: I did not test it but i guess following should work for your case
`SELECT Invoices.Id, Invoices.Billing_date, MainCustomer.Name, RefCustomer.Name FROM Invoices INNER JOIN Customers AS MainCustomer ON Invoices.Customer_Id=MainCustomer.Id LEFT JOIN Customers AS RefCustomer ON RefCustomer.Id=MainCustomer.Referred_ID`

Comment: "It's a MySQL from something like 2015..." -- This is MySQL 5.x

Comment: In MySQL 5.x you can traverse a limited number of references. If you want the direct referral, then it's easy. If you needed the "initial referral" going back to the very first one, you would need MySQL 8.x (recursive CTEs).

Answer (score 1):

You could use two time the customers  using an alias   for join the referred

```
    SELECT Invoices.Id, Invoices.Billing_date, Customers.Name, Referred.Name 
    FROM Invoices 
    INNER JOIN Customers ON Invoices.Customer_Id = Customers.Id
    INNER JOIN Customers Referred on Referred.id =  Customers.Referred_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

use Customers  table twice in join

```
 SELECT Invoices.Id, Invoices.Billing_date,
 c1.Name as customername,
c1.Referred_ID,
c2.Name as refername 
FROM Invoices INNER JOIN Customers c1 ON Invoices.Customer_Id = c1.Id
join Customers c2 on  c1.Id=c2.Referred_ID
```

Comment: @tnsaturday check now plz there was a typo

Comment: @tnsaturday i missed the on